# My cloth simulation is going through my face model no matter what I try

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

[image: screenshot of the desired effect]

I have a problem regarding my cloth simulation. I am working with a mesh of a face that I want to put under a cloth and see its lips move under the cloth. However, no matter the parameters I tweak, the cloth keeps going through the mesh. The main improvement in my tweaks was disabling the "Single sided" option in the collision object (face mesh). Increasing the quality of the simulation and the collisions didn't change anything, so I kept it low enough to be able to run the simulation easily.

Here are my inspirations regarding the project I want to make:

https://youtu.be/G1VBbHowAs8?si=MUI3eM1VRxx410D4
https://youtu.be/OguGDqf9xgs?si=UqKRAbVXyxhIHzsZ

I haven't found an answer on any question asked before, so I hope you will be able to help me on this. Thank you very much !

(I couldn't get the .blend file so it's in the .zip)

[image]

Comment: Hi. I've added a screenshot to your question. Cool effect. With the wireframe overlay+X-ray you can see better what's going on. The mesh faces are stretched as the face object pushes against it. The reason why it pushes through the cloth mesh at some point is because there is not enough geometry left to calculate the collision properly. For the same reason you can not see the shape of the lips when the mouth opens. Maybe try to fake the desired effect with a 2nd cloth simulation+a 2nd mesh at a certain frame.